Does puppeteer v21.6.1 supports Euler?
I write a demo to run puppeteer v21.6.1 in Euler;
 const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: true,
      args: ['--disable-gpu']
    });
 await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2', timeout: 120000 });

      const buffer = await page.pdf({
        format: 'a4',
        printBackground: true,
        scale: 0.7,
        margin: {left: '0.5cm', top: '1cm', right: '0.5cm', bottom: '1cm' }
      });

run Error: Protocol error (Page.navigate): Target closed;
And it is ok in ubantu
expected it works ok
